# VirtualBox host OS fake IP for apache

Tags: virtualbox, apache-http-server, php

I have apache installed on the guest machine. But in many scripts I have following condition:

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

Can I make a fake IP in Apache or Virtualbox?

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to acieve ? I don't understandFake IP.

Comment: I want to web server on the host machine determined the my IP as 127.0.0.1